# Django 1.5 migration issue

Tags: django, view, migration

I'm trying to migrate my view to django 1.5. I followed an example found on internet, but now I have some issue that I cannot solve by myself...

This view gives me an error: `SubListView() received an invalid keyword 'template_object_name'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class`

This is the view:

```
def forum(request, slug):
    try:
        f = Forum.objects.for_groups(request.user.groups.all()).select_related().get(slug=slug)
    except Forum.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    form = CreateThreadForm()
    child_forums = f.child.for_groups(request.user.groups.all())
    callable = SubListView.as_view(
                        queryset=f.thread_set.select_related().all(),
                        paginate_by=FORUM_PAGINATION,
                        template_object_name="thread",
                        template_name='forum/thread_list.html',
                        extra_context = {
                            'forum': f,
                            'child_forums': child_forums,
                            'form': form,
                        })
    return callable(request)
```

and this is the related `SubListView`:

```
class SubListView(ListView):
    extra_context = {}
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SubListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(self.extra_context)
        return context
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The attribute should be named `context_object_name`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts